# BigQuery to remove a string from an email address whose position is not fixed

Tags: google-bigquery

Can anyone please help in a query(Using BigQuery/GoogleSQL) that can remove an extra dot com in an email address, for example : test@yahoo.com.com
I have tried using regexp replace but unable to define a search for second dot in the string.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include more sample data, and note that there are in fact valid email addresses having 2 dots in the domain, e.g. `test@yahoo.co.uk`

Comment: yes,  I understand that. However, I don’t need an extra dot com suffixed with every email address. 
Some others I have are similar : sample1@hotmail.com.com
Sample2@gmail.com.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select email, regexp_replace(email, r'.com.com$', '.com') as email_out
from your_table
```

if to apply to dummy data like in below cte

```
with your_table as (
  select 'test@yahoo.com.com' email union all 
  select 'sample1@hotmail.com.com' union all
  select 'Sample2@gmail.com.com' union all
  select 'abc@gmail.com' 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. please also consider voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

To remove an extra `.com` from a `.com.com` ending, use:

```sql
SELECT email, REGEXP_REPLACE('\.com\.com$', '.com', email) AS email_out
FROM yourTable;
```